# What are the common and good usage of pre_randomize() and post_randomize() in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

How can I change/add constraint or constraint_mode in `pre_randomize()`?
I know I can overwrite results in `post_randomize` and I can call rand_mode on and off in `pre_randomize`, but I am looking for some additional functionality especially related to constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pre_randomize` is generally used to **set some pre-conditions before object randomization**. Here one can **print the results of previous randomization**, **set some variables on which the constraints are dependent** etc.

As you mentioned, `pre_randomize` can be used to set `rand_mode(0)` for any variable. It can be used to manipulate constraints as well.

`post_randomize` is used to **manipulate some variables** like ECC check, **print randomization result**, **manipulate some non-random fields based on existing randomization** etc.

One another usage of `post_randomize` is to **generate 'x' or 'z' in randomization process**. The randomization by default generates `0` and `1` known values only. But one can use the existing randomized variable to generate `x`/`z` values also.

Here is a dummy example of what we can do in `pre_randomize` and `post_randomize` functions. Here, depending on `non_rand_var`, we can **enable/disable the constraint mode and set the rand mode of any variable.** In the **post_randomize function, one can overwrite** 'my_x' variable byt 'x' or 'z'.

```
    class A;

    int non_rand_var;
    rand int rand_var;
    rand int rand_var2;
    rand logic my_x;

    constraint c1{non_rand_var==1 -> rand_var=='h5;}

      function new(int non_rand_var);
        this.non_rand_var = non_rand_var; // set non random variable
      endfunction

      function void pre_randomize();
        if(non_rand_var==5) begin // set randomization mode of rand_var2
          rand_var2.rand_mode(0);
          c1.constraint_mode(0); // disable constraint
        end
        $display("In pre randomize, non_rand_var=0x%0x rand_var=0x%0x",non_rand_var, rand_var);
      endfunction

      function void post_randomize();
        // my_x = $urandom_range(0,1) ? 0 : 'x;
        my_x = (non_rand_var==1) ? 0 : 'x; // Manipulate my_x to generate 'x' values
        $display("In post randomize, rand_var=0x%0x",rand_var);
      endfunction

    endclass

module top();
  A a=new(1);
  initial begin
    a.randomize(); 
    $display("Initial block:\na.my_x = 0x%0x\na.rand_var=0x%0x\na.non_rand_var=0x%0x\na.rand_var2=0x%0x",a.my_x,a.rand_var,a.non_rand_var,a.rand_var2);
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

`pre_randomize` & `post_randomize` function can have several uses based on the application.

Here is the list of few usage of those functions.

- Both functions can be overridden, and hence it can be possible to modify the randomization behavior with extended class
- Turn on/off few random variables
- Turn on/off few constraints
- Assignments to other nonrandom variable, on which the randomization is dependent
- Changing the weight of random variables, based on certain conditions

Typical usage of `pre_randomization` function is to generate an array of unique values.

```
class helper;
  randc bit [7:0] a;
endclass

class original;
  bit [7:0] unique[64];

  function void pre_randomize();
    helper h = new();
    foreach (unique[i])
    begin
      void'(h.randomize());
      unique[i] = h.a;
    end
  endfunction
endclass
```